# What's with the duck?

Tags: discussion, design

When I logged into Mi Yodeya after Yom Tov, I noticed something in the bottom right corner of the screen which wasn't there before:

[image]

What is this, and what does it do?

Comment: Probably just a April Fool's Day joke

Answer (score 3):

No one is exactly sure, but see [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck) to better understand the background, how to disable it/re-enable it, and some speculation on whether or not it has to do with April Fools.  (It still appears on Mi Yodeya today, but apparently April Fools stuff is buffered by 24h in each direction on SE.)